# adding two ggmaps onto the same plot using cowplot, ggarrange, gridextra or something similar

Tags: r

I am trying to plot some data onto a map but the geographical location of the map falls off the plot window.

What I currently have is:

[image]

The points which are "off" the map are the Canary Islands. How can I use `ggarrange`, `gridextra`, `cowplot` to plot the two maps (one for Spain) and (one for the Canary Islands) closer together on the same plot?

The geographical distance does not really need to be kept the same, just that I can take a map of the Canary Island and put it on the same plot as Spain.

Code:

```
library(ggrepel)
library(ggmap)
library(ggthemes)
register_google(key = "API-Key-Here")
spain <- get_map("Spain", zoom = 6, maptype = "watercolor")

ggmap(spain, extent = "normal") +
  geom_point(aes(x = long, y = lat),
             data = df)
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Status = c("Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt", 
"Non-Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt"), lat = c(41.6704722222222, 37.5457777777778, 
28.5199166666667, 43.2181666666667, 42.3101666666667, 39.4366666666667, 
43.3041666666667, 38.9904166666667, 37.8860555555556, 41.7338888888889, 
41.6675, 40.27, 40.47025, 37.3792777777778, 42.1364722222222, 
41.9009166666667, 40.4538611111111, 36.6889722222222, 40.9365555555556, 
40.3742777777778, 38.2944444444444, 42.8831111111111, 39.5630833333333, 
37.3763611111111, 42.8828611111111, 39.6073888888889, 40.3025, 
40.2632777777778, 41.4775, 42.7879444444444, 39.4905833333333, 
39.5767777777778, 41.5628611111111, 41.6444166666667, 41.3500277777778, 
40.4256944444444, 40.452, 41.0685555555556, 38.9838055555556, 
36.7501944444444, 38.8406111111111, 42.8219166666667, 39.9991388888889, 
41.2661944444444, 39.4541666666667, 37.0936944444444, 39.5104444444444, 
40.5352222222222, 41.6887222222222, 37.9665833333333, 39.9500277777778, 
42.5161111111111, 43.5538611111111, 40.8433333333333, 40.4226666666667, 
43.2549444444444, 37.2879722222222, 39.62125, 28.5060833333333, 
37.3676111111111, 41.56025, 42.4284444444444, 41.4403055555556, 
40.4299444444444, 40.4568888888889, 40.2696944444444, 41.3920833333333, 
42.0715277777778, 42.7856388888889, 42.8136111111111, 40.1141666666667, 
41.9845555555556, 42.9131111111111, 41.5640277777778, 36.8474444444444, 
41.3963611111111, 36.7601388888889, 40.4245833333333, 39.9975277777778, 
41.2798888888889, 42.4151666666667, 37.3898888888889, 40.3843055555556, 
39.46625, 41.6543611111111, 39.4028888888889, 41.4073333333333, 
36.7344444444444, 42.5710833333333, 37.4131666666667, 39.5728888888889, 
41.3903888888889, 43.1278333333333, 38.7740555555556, 41.5875, 
39.4703611111111, 37.1710833333333, 38.1808888888889, 41.4193055555556, 
39.6569166666667, 41.4014722222222, 37.3245, 38.9906111111111, 
42.0043055555556, 43.3568611111111, 37.2226111111111, 37.3792222222222, 
42.3940833333333, 40.3996944444444, 40.4993611111111, 41.4029166666667, 
36.8272222222222, 42.3398333333333, 42.80775, 42.2228333333333, 
37.7649166666667, 40.4871111111111, 39.4499166666667, 43.3280277777778, 
39.07325, 39.2015833333333, 40.4496111111111, 41.5461111111111, 
40.4228333333333, 41.1663611111111, 39.561, 41.4353055555556, 
39.1635555555556, 40.4083888888889, 43.3638055555556, 36.4603055555556, 
40.4386388888889, 28.0960833333333, 42.5161111111111, 40.4454722222222, 
41.9295, 38.0858055555556, 42.3385, 41.3935555555556, 36.5163055555556, 
40.0631944444444, 40.4888611111111, 39.5725833333333, 41.5874722222222, 
41.3595, 40.4463055555556, 37.4906388888889, 43.3635, 36.5669166666667, 
40.4616944444444, 40.4496111111111, 38.6637777777778, 28.6806666666667, 
37.2202222222222, 41.9408888888889, 40.03225, 37.4238055555556, 
41.3261111111111, 40.23325, 41.58525, 42.3308333333333, 38.9905, 
37.9394166666667, 38.6421388888889, 38.0501111111111, 43.5475, 
43.5124444444444, 39.0624166666667, 41.6704722222222, 41.3488055555556, 
42.3360555555556, 37.5396666666667, 38.3449444444444, 42.6015277777778, 
42.0485833333333, 43.4286944444444, 40.4405833333333, 37.3729444444444, 
40.441, 41.4299722222222, 40.4215, 40.4433888888889, 41.4317777777778, 
41.48775, 41.3946666666667, 40.47025, 40.4065555555556, 40.6596666666667, 
43.1345277777778, 42.2660833333333, 41.6896111111111, 28.4905277777778, 
41.3905833333333, 41.3920555555556, 28.0925277777778, 43.25875, 
43.2261944444444, 40.48875, 43.4174444444444, 37.5701388888889, 
37.8818333333333, 40.4748611111111, 40.3545277777778, 40.4247222222222, 
38.3465833333333, 40.44725, 28.1, 42.1499444444444, 37.9839166666667, 
42.8517777777778, 41.9643888888889, 38.2488611111111, 41.216, 
28.4606666666667, 39.4394722222222, 37.6696388888889, 40.9457222222222, 
39.0189444444444, 41.3925, 41.3662222222222, 36.7419444444444, 
41.6488055555556, 40.4599722222222, 36.5981388888889, 41.6515277777778, 
40.5388055555556, 43.3518333333333, 28.1129166666667, 43.2610277777778, 
40.4494166666667, 41.3740833333333, 36.7201666666667, 43.2476388888889, 
37.3882222222222, 37.32525, 43.4074722222222, 41.2406666666667, 
37.3801666666667, 40.4596666666667, 40.4751666666667, 43.2631111111111, 
36.2498611111111, 36.7220833333333, 40.4173888888889, 42.7997222222222, 
39.1871944444444, 38.0891944444444, 40.62275, 37.8918333333333, 
39.4720555555556, 40.3292777777778, 38.8288055555556, 42.06175, 
41.2965833333333, 40.48775, 37.3816111111111, 42.0151944444444, 
28.1489444444444, 40.3826111111111, 43.3275277777778, 42.8298888888889, 
36.9254722222222, 37.5643333333333, 41.3266944444444, 41.51325, 
40.4563333333333, 42.22875, 41.3903333333333, 39.5786111111111, 
39.9864444444444, 42.5047222222222, 39.4428333333333, 40.4106944444444, 
41.8148055555556, 41.6473888888889, 39.4563055555556, 38.7713333333333, 
43.5165277777778, 42.2356666666667, 42.306, 40.0744166666667, 
41.4032222222222, 40.12, 41.1972222222222, 42.0071111111111, 
41.5978055555556, 41.3950555555556, 39.4653055555556, 43.0626111111111, 
43.2983888888889, 37.2783333333333, 39.335, 37.7705277777778, 
41.1965833333333, 41.3964166666667, 42.8287777777778, 42.4361111111111, 
40.419, 41.4070833333333, 40.4871388888889, 41.7653888888889, 
42.5027222222222, 41.6028611111111, 43.529, 40.46225, 41.6995277777778, 
40.45675, 41.6108888888889, 42.4151666666667, 39.56175, 41.6725, 
40.4381111111111, 40.4413611111111, 36.2938333333333, 40.4378888888889, 
42.8576666666667, 36.7053055555556, 39.4268333333333, 37.5965833333333, 
42.5971666666667, 27.7564444444444, 38.2569722222222, 42.1610277777778, 
37.9757777777778, 39.9640277777778, 39.5128888888889, 41.3891388888889, 
41.41525, 39.40325, 40.4325, 39.4809722222222, 38.9776944444444, 
39.5451111111111, 41.6169166666667, 40.4785, 37.8848611111111, 
36.7727777777778, 40.2759444444444, 38.9924444444444, 42.12575, 
41.0680555555556, 43.2625833333333, 36.7200555555556, 38.2060833333333, 
43.3221666666667, 40.4271944444444, 42.2341666666667, 43.2578333333333, 
36.7305833333333, 37.3570277777778, 37.5265, 40.9695833333333, 
41.75075, 41.3825277777778, 39.9862777777778, 36.5496111111111, 
40.2414722222222, 41.4711111111111, 39.2122777777778, 39.4904444444444, 
40.1670277777778, 39.4784722222222, 42.7950277777778, 41.7224722222222, 
38.9111944444444, 39.9841111111111, 40.42875, 39.9255, 38.9616388888889, 
43.3730833333333, 40.4093888888889, 42.5773333333333, 40.4829444444444, 
40.3484166666667, 41.6115833333333, 42.9381944444444, 40.4221944444444, 
40.5006666666667, 39.8763888888889, 38.0863888888889, 40.4509722222222, 
41.6292777777778, 41.3835555555556, 40.2628055555556, 41.5244722222222, 
41.5591666666667, 36.6058611111111, 40.9436666666667, 40.4373611111111, 
42.16375, 37.9093055555556, 41.4004722222222, 40.4055555555556, 
37.3924722222222, 39.4243333333333, 40.7665555555556, 42.4316111111111, 
40.4367222222222, 37.1858611111111, 41.3950555555556, 43.3172777777778, 
42.7997222222222, 40.4371388888889, 40.4672777777778, 40.2428888888889, 
39.4811944444444, 37.4202777777778, 40.1907222222222, 41.9786111111111, 
37.3831388888889, 41.5284166666667, 38.9088333333333, 40.3594166666667, 
39.4964444444444, 38.1407777777778, 40.4185277777778, 41.69925, 
42.3705555555556, 41.5548888888889, 41.5411388888889, 40.2711944444444, 
41.1559444444444, 39.4884166666667, 40.46975, 37.8874722222222, 
41.45825, 41.1216388888889, 37.9931944444444, 38.9856388888889, 
39.4807222222222, 41.5330833333333, 40.9521666666667, 39.6185, 
40.3497777777778, 42.4323333333333, 40.42775, 40.4369444444444, 
38.8289722222222, 40.933, 39.36675, 28.1159444444444, 39.5456666666667, 
41.7610277777778, 41.3958611111111, 40.3861111111111, 40.4636388888889, 
39.5843888888889, 40.4297777777778, 41.6218333333333, 37.38975, 
40.4213055555556, 39.2231944444444, 42.3557777777778, 39.5727777777778, 
37.9845555555556, 43.2643055555556, 40.29325, 40.4448888888889, 
38.3643888888889, 38.4706111111111, 28.4891944444444, 41.5606666666667, 
37.37575, 39.57825, 37.4361944444444, 39.2761944444444, 37.3882222222222, 
38.7692222222222, 43.4843888888889, 40.4619722222222, 40.5084166666667, 
39.4751666666667, 38.1971944444444, 40.94825, 40.4901666666667, 
39.71825, 43.2699444444444, 37.5168888888889, 41.9057222222222, 
43.0685555555556, 40.61625, 43.2717222222222, 42.4052222222222, 
41.4245555555555, 37.5406666666667, 40.48275, 42.7818333333333, 
38.1051944444444, 40.4398333333333, 43.2817777777778, 41.5427222222222, 
40.4924166666667, 42.2760555555556, 38.3389722222222, 36.7311944444444, 
39.4675833333333, 40.4333055555556, 38.34675, 40.4148611111111, 
40.6286111111111), long = c(0.817138888888889, -5.21675, -16.339, 
-2.73508333333333, -1.96922222222222, -0.468166666666667, -1.98005555555556, 
-1.86655555555556, -4.77980555555556, 1.82816666666667, -0.957194444444444, 
-3.83508333333333, -3.58261111111111, -5.97788888888889, -0.409361111111111, 
-8.87294444444444, -3.69472222222222, -4.45552777777778, -4.11383333333333, 
-3.64438888888889, -0.609166666666667, -8.52730555555556, 3.21916666666667, 
-5.96113888888889, -8.52888888888889, 2.63475, -3.69994444444444, 
-3.70133333333333, 1.91847222222222, -8.89066666666667, -0.400166666666667, 
2.42216666666667, 2.24413888888889, -0.767861111111111, 2.10238888888889, 
-3.68441666666667, -3.99861111111111, 1.0565, -0.243666666666667, 
-3.87747222222222, 0.106416666666667, -1.65086111111111, -0.0398333333333333, 
2.00586111111111, -0.377, -3.63433333333333, 2.53061111111111, 
-3.64788888888889, -4.68088888888889, -1.08663888888889, -0.0661666666666667, 
-5.76636111111111, -5.91922222222222, -1.88769444444444, -3.68161111111111, 
-2.91883333333333, -6.06483333333333, -0.306416666666667, -13.8516111111111, 
-5.75013888888889, 2.02619444444444, -8.64819444444444, 2.16666666666667, 
-3.67880555555556, -3.63683333333333, -3.68577777777778, 2.13186111111111, 
2.95358333333333, 0.692416666666667, -1.64144444444444, -6.79208333333333, 
2.82019444444444, -8.52508333333333, 2.02094444444444, -2.30394444444444, 
2.16438888888889, -2.62394444444444, -3.71355555555556, 3.83630555555556, 
1.97697222222222, 1.13236111111111, -4.77255555555556, -3.76547222222222, 
-0.3545, -4.721, -3.12313888888889, 2.14025, -4.414, -7.97491666666667, 
-1.74661111111111, 2.65877777777778, 2.15566666666667, -2.54238888888889, 
-4.83147222222222, 2.25144444444444, -6.38716666666667, -3.59602777777778, 
-1.12555555555556, 2.21047222222222, 2.69933333333333, 2.13552777777778, 
-5.42241666666667, -0.523805555555556, -5.67652777777778, -5.85677777777778, 
-3.6865, -5.96988888888889, -8.82713888888889, -3.40605555555556, 
-3.65777777777778, 2.00558333333333, -2.42758333333333, -8.01077777777778, 
-1.61763888888889, -8.756, -1.49969444444444, -3.35841666666667, 
-2.67891666666667, -3.03319444444444, -0.262694444444444, -2.16194444444444, 
-3.66927777777778, 2.21666666666667, -3.70775, 1.10633333333333, 
3.20797222222222, 2.20358333333333, -0.420194444444444, -3.78252777777778, 
-5.86308333333333, -5.72405555555556, -3.67472222222222, -15.4798333333333, 
-5.76636111111111, -3.672, 2.79458333333333, -0.654694444444444, 
-1.80611111111111, 2.14241666666667, -6.28091666666667, -4.22827777777778, 
-3.38786111111111, 2.66088888888889, 2.18066666666667, 2.12058333333333, 
-3.67397222222222, -2.77266666666667, -4.04888888888889, -4.63008333333333, 
-3.69386111111111, -3.68911111111111, -6.37325, -17.7675277777778, 
-7.40808333333333, 2.24519444444444, -3.60875, -6.03633333333333, 
2.03097222222222, -3.7675, 1.62405555555556, -3.70102777777778, 
-0.159277777777778, -1.13566666666667, -3.46277777777778, -1.01233333333333, 
-5.83469444444444, -8.18083333333333, -1.0585, -3.68569444444444, 
1.83744444444444, 0.0902222222222222, -5.08158333333333, -0.481416666666667, 
-8.93775, 2.25819444444444, -5.8395, -3.69575, -5.99944444444444, 
-3.78763888888889, 2.18433333333333, -3.67316666666667, -3.70486111111111, 
2.21886111111111, 2.29738888888889, 2.17052777777778, -3.58261111111111, 
-3.69747222222222, -4.68713888888889, -4.57605555555556, 3.14613888888889, 
2.18480555555556, -16.3150555555556, 2.14983333333333, 2.14497222222222, 
-15.4875, -2.94077777777778, -8.67352777777778, -3.67141666666667, 
-3.84527777777778, -1.26391666666667, -4.80755555555556, -3.72605555555556, 
-3.54094444444444, -3.71225, -0.497611111111111, -3.68633333333333, 
-15.4438888888889, 0.694138888888889, -0.687694444444444, -2.72516666666667, 
3.03497222222222, -0.810416666666667, -0.445916666666667, -16.3024444444444, 
-0.356972222222222, -1.69816666666667, -5.653, -1.89141666666667, 
2.142, 0.917055555555556, -3.51983333333333, -0.885527777777778, 
-3.78311111111111, -6.22872222222222, -0.879333333333333, -3.64675, 
-8.38947222222222, -15.4501388888889, -2.94813888888889, -3.50786111111111, 
2.15691666666667, -4.40863888888889, -8.58322222222222, -6.2005, 
-5.41697222222222, -3.85483333333333, 1.57663888888889, -5.97452777777778, 
-4.07702777777778, -3.87536111111111, -2.93827777777778, -5.96716666666667, 
-4.44661111111111, -3.67841666666667, -1.61169444444444, -0.509027777777778, 
-0.713138888888889, -3.16030555555556, -4.77166666666667, -0.38425, 
-1.10580555555556, 0.0636666666666667, -1.60544444444444, -4.91025, 
-3.66436111111111, -6.00352777777778, -4.51780555555556, -15.6489444444444, 
-3.72941666666667, -8.40058333333333, -1.60191666666667, -2.45769444444444, 
-1.80772222222222, 2.09430555555556, 2.12591666666667, -3.69205555555556, 
-2.04875, 2.13669444444444, 2.66511111111111, -0.0555277777777778, 
-8.64872222222222, -2.09369444444444, -4.71066666666667, 2.99816666666667, 
-0.862222222222222, -0.404166666666667, -4.83544444444444, -5.68211111111111, 
-8.72361111111111, -8.7925, -0.213527777777778, 2.16038888888889, 
-3.78861111111111, 1.57025, 2.82447222222222, 2.26580555555556, 
2.16972222222222, -6.38005555555555, -2.49580555555556, -2.92102777777778, 
-7.15366666666667, -1.92911111111111, -1.50019444444444, 1.63547222222222, 
2.15366666666667, -1.61872222222222, -8.06702777777778, -3.70927777777778, 
2.20930555555556, -3.88725, 2.253, -8.01375, 2.28469444444444, 
-5.67897222222222, -3.69275, 2.83436111111111, -3.62436111111111, 
0.635805555555556, 1.13236111111111, -0.398444444444444, -2.32713888888889, 
-3.66616666666667, -3.64033333333333, -5.30180555555556, -3.69161111111111, 
-8.65727777777778, -6.12827777777778, -0.372777777777778, -5.20797222222222, 
-5.60369444444444, -15.6834166666667, -0.704527777777778, -8.61905555555556, 
-1.12419444444444, -4.82872222222222, -0.432138888888889, 2.12872222222222, 
2.17794444444444, -0.403194444444444, -3.72511111111111, -0.356861111111111, 
-1.86930555555556, -0.568972222222222, 0.620055555555556, -3.62994444444444, 
-4.78202777777778, -2.81730555555556, -3.77058333333333, -1.85677777777778, 
3.13338888888889, 1.08969444444444, -2.93233333333333, -4.40833333333333, 
-3.51383333333333, -1.93938888888889, -3.69519444444444, -8.71163888888889, 
-2.92541666666667, -2.63375, -1.81391666666667, -5.24908333333333, 
-5.66947222222222, -2.45741666666667, 2.17072222222222, -0.0361388888888889, 
-4.61625, -3.70072222222222, 2.08130555555556, -4.17666666666667, 
-0.368694444444444, -3.62847222222222, -0.459861111111111, -7.83488888888889, 
2.92991666666667, -6.35619444444444, -0.0349166666666667, -3.67583333333333, 
-0.196416666666667, -0.584416666666667, -5.83575, -3.72916666666667, 
-5.54486111111111, -3.67169444444444, -3.9075, -4.70522222222222, 
-3.5735, -3.65663888888889, -3.33708333333333, -4.03175, -0.723527777777778, 
-3.99772222222222, -0.91575, 2.17794444444444, -3.85211111111111, 
1.68869444444444, 2.00319444444444, -5.79841666666667, -4.11797222222222, 
-3.68013888888889, 0.894888888888889, -4.77966666666667, 2.14938888888889, 
-3.69208333333333, -5.71969444444444, -0.416777777777778, -5.53880555555556, 
-8.65072222222222, -3.63055555555556, -5.78702777777778, 2.19658333333333, 
-8.35730555555556, -1.61169444444444, -3.70311111111111, -3.67044444444444, 
-3.31891666666667, -0.4585, -4.48425, -3.68294444444444, 2.82188888888889, 
-6.006, 1.87663888888889, 1.43213888888889, 0.403222222222222, 
2.53561111111111, -0.889944444444444, -3.80233333333333, -6.34722222222222, 
1.77463888888889, 2.00763888888889, 2.21391666666667, -3.91988888888889, 
1.10636111111111, -1.10344444444444, -3.69972222222222, -4.78136111111111, 
2.25544444444444, 1.24405555555556, -1.13088888888889, -3.93213888888889, 
-0.329388888888889, -4.73355555555556, -5.67308333333333, 3.36144444444444, 
-3.80061111111111, -8.64516666666667, -3.68586111111111, -3.69291666666667, 
0.0135555555555556, -4.10211111111111, -0.432944444444444, -15.4196666666667, 
-0.301555555555556, -0.797833333333333, 2.18977777777778, -5.75347222222222, 
-3.69361111111111, -0.283111111111111, -3.71386111111111, 2.66955555555556, 
-5.99322222222222, -3.71816666666667, -6.15216666666667, -3.67861111111111, 
2.65644444444444, -1.13497222222222, -2.93436111111111, -3.79402777777778, 
-3.7905, -0.421361111111111, -0.775805555555556, -16.3810555555556, 
2.02388888888889, -5.97602777777778, 2.66738888888889, -2.72422222222222, 
-0.382527777777778, -6.2005, 0.0903888888888889, -8.23372222222222, 
-3.87611111111111, -3.64586111111111, -0.403777777777778, -1.22302777777778, 
-5.67980555555556, -3.88055555555556, 2.90497222222222, -2.04583333333333, 
-6.26744444444444, -1.72683333333333, -2.48863888888889, -3.70233333333333, 
-8.23238888888889, -8.57763888888889, 2.15894444444444, -5.07766666666667, 
-3.72975, -8.88322222222222, -1.86286111111111, -3.623, -1.67677777777778, 
2.11433333333333, -3.86161111111111, -8.73730555555555, -0.508472222222222, 
-3.73180555555556, -0.373555555555556, -3.28533333333333, -0.768027777777778, 
-3.68925, -4.01866666666667)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -500L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possible solution with `viewport()` from the `grid` package.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(grid)

Canaries <- df %>% 
  filter(lat < 35)
notCanaries <- df %>% 
  filter(lat >= 35)

notCanaries_plot <- ggmap(spain, extent = "normal") +
  geom_point(aes(x = long, y = lat),
             data = notCanaries) + 
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        plot.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0 ,0), "mm"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "transparent"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(title = "Not Canary Islands")

canaries <- get_map("Canary Islands", zoom = 7, maptype = "watercolor")

Canaries_plot <- ggmap(canaries, extent = "normal") +
  geom_point(aes(x = long, y = lat),
             data = Canaries) + 
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        plot.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0 ,0), "mm"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "transparent"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(title = "Canary Islands")

grid.newpage()
mainmap <- viewport(width = .8, height = 1, x = 0.7, y = 0.6) # main map
insetmap <- viewport(width = 0.36, height = 0.3, x = 0.2, y = 0.2)
print(notCanaries_plot, vp = mainmap) 
print(Canaries_plot, vp = insetmap)
```

[image]